Finding Latitude and Longitude from Preferred Easting and Northing using Python code - UK Grid
Calling all GIS techers: I am trying to gather some cool environmental data analysis skills to build a portfolio with, i would really appreciate it if any pros had some insight on how to covert eastings and northings to longitude and latitude. i have a CSV file with prefferedE and N columns, all are in Scotland.



Grid ref
PrefE.
PreN




NJ910066
391095
806625


NJ916060
391650
806050


NJ930053
393050
805350



I would like to convert them into Long and Lat so i can later perform a T-test for fungal species distribution (i'll be back :)
I really have no idea where to start.
Thank you in advance.
